# GitHub Mac Desktop clone same repository multiple times missing repository name from list

Tags: repository, github-for-mac

How can you make multiple clones of the same repository on your local computer with GitHub Mac Desktop?  After you make the first clone, the repository name disappears from the GitHub Desktop clone choice list.

Related to this, I cloned a GitHub repository onto my local machine, then decided I didn't want it in that location.  I simply deleted (trashed) the old repository and tried to clone it again, but could not, because the repository name was not listed.  It turned out that because the repository was still in the trash, GitHub Desktop didn't recognize it as gone.  I emptied the trash and it saw that it was gone and asked if I wanted to remove the repository.  I answered YES and then the repository name appeared in the clone choice list.

Answer (score 2):

You can't clone the same repo twice from the GUI so, instead use command line `git clone` for that and then you can use the File->Add Local Repository item to select the path and it will show up.

The annoying thing is that having multiple clones of the repo in the Repository List will cause them all to have exactly the same name, because GitHub Mac Desktop doesn't show the paths. Fortunately the order doesn't change and you can always (right click->open in terminal) to see which is which.

If you want to delete a repo that you have cloned - you need to remove it in Github for Mac (right click->Remove) which just removes it from being tracked in the repository list. Now you can delete it from the Finder.
Delete from Finder and then remove from Github for Mac works too.

Comment: I don't know if this is just Github desktop for Mac, but I wasn't able to choose the directory name independently from the Github repository name, which was the first problem in identifying them from the list. So I cloned them in different parent folders. But worse, when I went to add them, it would add the wrong one. I tripled checked the path I was adding, but it still added the wrong local repository. Is there any way around this?